# what this error description means in fread()

Tags: c, ubuntu, fread

I'm learning the fopen() on Ubuntu, and here is my code. Could you help on what is the specific failure reason?

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    char reg_filename[] = "/home/chuck/Documents/enable";
    FILE* f;
    char val[2];

    f = fopen(reg_filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror(reg_filename);
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    setvbuf(f, (char *)NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    if (fread(&val, sizeof(val), 1, f) == 0) {
        perror(reg_filename);
        printf("Read_error\n");
        return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**Build & run it...**

```
chuck@ubuntu:~/Documents$ gcc a.c
chuck@ubuntu:~/Documents$ ./a.out
/home/chuck/Documents/enable: Success
Read_error
```

In the code, "enable" is a file in my system.
What I know is that it fails on fread() since "Read_error" pops. But what this "Success" mean? If it failed, why it gives the "Success" word?

And about how to use the fread(), I'm totally new... This fread() will read from f (the file path) with size of val[] length and read to val[], right?

And does it related with the val[] size, in this case, I just put it 2 then sizeof(val) should be 3? Then how will fread gonna to work to read the f (/home/chuck/Documents/enable) into it?

Comment: Type `man fread` in your command line. Also, note that you are using the `&` address of operator on an array, that is not needed and in fact it's strictly wrong, because even though both base addresses are the same `arr + 1` is not the same as `&arr + 1`.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: are your aware that the `enable` file is empty? That's why `fread` returns 0 because it returns the number of items read which is 0 in this case.

Comment: Oh, yes, my enable is empty. what a fool of me...Just put some words in enable file, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the man page for [`fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmembFILE *" stream );
```

And it clearly states,

> The function fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes long,
>          from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location
>          given by ptr.

Importantly, you might want to change

```
fread(&val, sizeof(val), 1, f)
```

to

```
fread(val, sizeof(val), 1, f)
```

So it would return `0` if your `enable` file could be empty!

Answer (score 0):

If you read a short count, (i.e. fewer items than you expected) then `fread()` has either encountered an error or reached the end of file before reading enough bytes.

In your case, you read 0 items instead of 1 item so there was either an error or end of file was encountered before reading a whole item. Use [feof()](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-feof/) or ferror() to find out whether you have end of file or an error. i.e. if `ferror()` returns non zero, there was an error and `errno` is meaningful.